# Looking for a non-trivial 3 layered asp.net example

Tags: asp.net, web, three-tier

I am looking for an example of an asp.net website(with source), implemented with 3 layer architecture and has some complexities like user authentication and user permissions, etc. .

Does anybody know such an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're favouring ASP.NET MVC (and I would suggest you should be) then [Nerd Dinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) ([source](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)) is one of the best examples on structuring an application.

Personally I feel that rather than focus on n-Tier/3-Tier architectures you should focus your efforts on responsibly designing web applications using principles like SOLID.

Comment: "Personally I feel that rather than focus on n-Tier/3-Tier architectures you should focus your efforts on responsibly designing web applications using principles like SOLID."

Good advice, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

KiGG is a nice application to use for reference.

Source code can be found on codeplex: http://kigg.codeplex.com/